# SQL subquery / join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a subquery / join to compare a set of rows in a table to other rows in the same table.

Excerpt data set:

```
Guid                        MonitorsetID    groupName
26464009405210800000000000  2162            ~templates.root
26464009405210800000000000  2161            ~templates.root
26464009405210800000000000  1464            ~templates.root
26464009405210800000000000  1224            ~templates.root
321794737607583             2162            lab.root.abc
321794737607583             2161            lab.root.abc
321794737607583             1464            lab.root.abc
321794737607583             1224            lab.root.abc
500311571061532             2196            lab.root.abc
500311571061532             2195            lab.root.abc
500311571061532             1464            lab.root.abc
500311571061532             1224            lab.root.abc
129478194721498             1464            lab.root.def
129478194721498             1224            lab.root.def
```

I need to result on which MonitorsetID(s) exist on one particular Guid '26464009405210800000000000'  but are "missing" for a select group of other Guid records, for this example all Guids with groupName 'lab.root.abc'. In the exerpt above, there are currently 4 MonitorsetIDs matching this Guid: 2162, 2161, 1464, 1224. 2162 and 2161 are "missing" from the Guid '500311571061532'.

The result set I would like is:

```
Guid                        MonitorsetID    groupName
500311571061532             2162            lab.root.abc
500311571061532             2161            lab.root.abc
```

Or, the following would also work:

```
Guid                        MonitorsetID    groupName           Guid                MonitorsetID    groupName
26464009405210800000000000  2162            ~templates.root     500311571061532     NULL            lab.root.abc
26464009405210800000000000  2161            ~templates.root     500311571061532     NULL            lab.root.abc
```

I'm able to get the inverse of the result I want with the following:

```
SELECT VMAA.agentguid, VMAA.MonitorsetID
FROM [vMonitorsetAgentAssignment] VMAA
LEFT JOIN [vMonitorsetAgentAssignment] VMAA2
ON VMAA.MonitorsetID = VMAA2.MonitorsetID

WHERE
    VMAA.agentguid in 
    (
    SELECT AgentGuid FROM vMonitorsetAgentAssignment VMAA
    WHERE VMAA.groupName = 'lab.root.abc'
    )
    AND
    VMAA2.agentguid = '26464009405210876452365122'

ORDER BY agentGuid, MonitorsetID
```

My attempts at getting the needed results by adding a condition to the JOIN ON clause with "IS NULL", etc. just return blank results.

Comment: How about guid=129478194721498,  2162 and 2161 also missing from this guid, do you want list them as well?

Comment: Yes, 2162 and 2161 are missing from Guid 129478194721498 also, but I intend to target the query against a specific group of Guids and ignore others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will extract missing ids for both guids 129478194721498 and 500311571061532.

```
with createddata as (
  select *
  from
  (
     select distinct guid, groupname from vMonitorsetAgentAssignment 
     where guid <> '26464009405210800000000000'
  ) a
  cross join
  (
     select monitorsetid from vMonitorsetAgentAssignment 
     where guid = '26464009405210800000000000'
  ) b
)
select x.*
from createddata x
left join vMonitorsetAgentAssignment y
  on x.guid = y.guid
  and x.monitorsetid = y.monitorsetid
  and x.groupname = y.groupname
  and y.guid <> '26464009405210800000000000'
where y.guid is null

Results
|            guid |    groupname | monitorsetid |
|-----------------|--------------|--------------|
| 129478194721498 | lab.root.def |         2162 |
| 129478194721498 | lab.root.def |         2161 |
| 500311571061532 | lab.root.abc |         2162 |
| 500311571061532 | lab.root.abc |         2161 |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80719/33

**Ignore the answer below**

Take a look at this query for the results you described as desired:

```
  select a.* from 
  vMonitorsetAgentAssignment a
  left join (
      select monitorsetid as masterids from vMonitorsetAgentAssignment 
      where guid = '26464009405210800000000000'
  ) b on a.monitorsetid = b.masterids
  where not guid = '26464009405210800000000000'
        and masterids is null

Result:
|            Guid | MonitorsetID |    groupName |
|-----------------|--------------|--------------|
| 500311571061532 |         2196 | lab.root.abc |
| 500311571061532 |         2195 | lab.root.abc |
```

Comment: Nope - Adam needs monitor set ids 2161 and 2162 to come back. You've got the wrong monitor ids.

Comment: Very strange, I've tried your updated query above and I return blank results against my production table, but I see the SQL fiddle output working as intended. I need to look into this more to see if I've somehow misrepresented the schema...

Comment: Oops, I had copied the wrong Guid to my example data above. The query does get me the intended results, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Get all possible combinations of the GUIDs in the groupName you are filtering over along with the MonitorsetID's of the GUID you are filtering on (by cross-joining from the base table to a distinct set of MonitorsetIDs for the GUID you are filtering on).

Once you have that data-set, it becomes a simple left-join from that derived data set over to your base table again on guid/monitersetIds that don't exist:

```
with root_data as
(
    select  distinct a.agentguid, b.MonitorsetID, a.groupName
    from    vMonitorsetAgentAssignment a
    cross join (
            select  distinct MonitorsetID
            from    vMonitorsetAgentAssignment d
            where   d.agentguid = '26464009405210800000000000'
        ) b
    where   a.groupName = 'lab.root.abc'
)
select  *
from    root_data d
left join vMonitorsetAgentAssignment a
on      a.agentguid = d.agentguid
and     a.MonitorsetID = d.MonitorsetID
where   a.agentguid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select '500311571061532' as agentguid, a.MonitorsetID
from vMonitorsetAgentAssignment a left join
     vMonitorsetAgentAssignment a2
     on a2.agentguid = '500311571061532' and
        a.MonitorsetID = a2.MonitorsetID
where a.agentguid = '321794737607583' and
      a2.agentguid is null;
```

I'm not sure where the group comes from.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what you need.

```
WITH monitor_sets AS (
    SELECT MonitorsetID, agentguid
    FROM vMonitorsetAgentAssignment
    WHERE agentguid = '26464009405210876452365122'
)

SELECT DISTINCT vmaa.agentguid AS guid_with_missing, ms.agentguid, ms.MonitorsetID
FROM vMonitorsetAgentAssignment vmaa
CROSS JOIN monitor_sets ms
WHERE vmaa.groupName = 'lab.root.abc' 
    AND vmaa.MonitorsetID NOT IN (SELECT MonitorsetID FROM monitor_sets)
    AND vmaa.agentguid NOT IN (SELECT agentguid FROM vMonitorsetAgentAssignment WHERE MonitorsetID = ms.MonitorsetID)
```